# SonarQube null pointers should not be dereferenced on try/catch

Tags: java, sonarqube

Currently I'm working with SonarQube solving issues but I'm facing a trouble to how handle null pointers that shouldn't be dereferenced. This issues is displayed by SonarQube.

My main problem is because I'm doing a restTemplate.exchange with try-catch and declaring a variable with null value before the clause try and then using it inside the try. Finally my method is returning a response with value of restTemplate.

```
public MyDto exchangeUrlRequest(String url){
 ResponseEntity<MyDto> responseDto = null;
 try{
  responseDto = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.PUT...
 }catch(HttpClientErrorException e){
   //some code here
 }
  return responseDto.getBody();
}
```

The expected result here is solve the issue with sonarqube. How handle the initialization of "responseDto" without "null" because is throwing the issue on sonar.

I already tried to put `ResponseEntity<MyDto> responseDto` inside my try clause assigning and returning the respective value but its mandatory to return something out the try/catch. Put a `new ResponseEntity` is wrong because I won't know what will be the answer for the status of http.

Answer (score 2):

Your code needs to do something about the possible `NullPointerException` when some exception is caught, because in this scenario the `responseDto` will be null.

There are many ways to resolve this. The solution that I recommend is not work with `null` returns or variables on Java, try to [avoid](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/373751/172464) it. You can use `Optional` instead.

So, this code should address the Sonar problem:

```
public Optional<MyDto> exchangeUrlRequest(String url){

     ResponseEntity<MyDto> responseDto;
     try{
          responseDto = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.PUT...);
     } catch(HttpClientErrorException e) {
         //some code here
     }

     if (responseDto == null) {
         return Optional.empty();
     } 
     return Optional.of(responseDto.getBody());
}
```

You can also eliminate the `null` check using `Optional<ResponseEntity<MyDto>>`, like:

```
public Optional<MyDto> exchangeUrlRequest(String url){

     Optional<ResponseEntity<MyDto>> optResponseDto = Optional.empty();
     try{
          optResponseDto = Optional.of(restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.PUT...));
     } catch(HttpClientErrorException e) {
         //some code here
     }

     if (!optResponseDto.isPresent()) {
         return Optional.empty();
     } 
     return optResponseDto.get().getBody();
}
```

Even I don't recommend this, you can just check the null `responseDto` without any use of `Optional`:

```
public MyDto exchangeUrlRequest(String url){

     ResponseEntity<MyDto> responseDto = null;
     try{
          responseDto = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.PUT...);
     } catch(HttpClientErrorException e) {
         //some code here
     }

     if (responseDto == null) {
         return null;
     } 
     return responseDto.getBody();
}
```